# Apache as reverse proxy: synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, reverse-proxy, mpm-prefork

I'm using Apache to serve static content, and then reverse proxy-ing to a Rails server to process dynamic content, some of which can take a long time to generate. When Apache hands off a request to a reverse proxy, is an Apache process used up just sitting there waiting for a response (im using prefork mpm), or can it go off and process other requests, and just handle the response from the Rails server when the response is ready?

Comment: how the hell is this 'not a real question'?? Its clearly stated, and the answer directly affects whether I can use apache or whether I have to switch to nginx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Apache Prefork MPM you will have at least one process for each concurrent request. And, each process will be serving one or zero requests (idle or spare).

So the process doing the reverse proxy to Rail, will be blocked till it gets completed (or error). Anyway, another connection can be open to the same server.